# Replace only a part of a subsetted vector

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I've got a data frame called someMatrix. Now in this matrix I want to replace only the first three rows of the 4 column.

I came up with this idea.

```
(someMatrix[,4])[1:3] <- replacement
```

but I get following error: `could not find function "(<-"`

Any idea how I could solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: the error is telling you to remove the parentheses

Comment: @rawr OK, although i'm curious about this: why exactly doesn't it work? since without the assignment part, the statement works perfectly..

Comment: @agenis, that's exactly what got me thinking as well

Comment: @agenis `(` is just a function like most things in R (type `\`(\``). It doesn't have a method for `<-`, ie, extract/replace. You use brackets for indexing/extracting/replacing. Type `methods('[<-')` to see some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may subset with brackets as many times you want, without bothering with parentheses:

```
a <- cbind(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
a[1:5, ][2:3, ][, 2][1]
```